# Why the quote is placed at the beginning of string?

Tags: replace

To match the string behind the `:` :

```
TE: trailer
```

The expression will convert the string into `trailer`:

```
:1s/\v(.{-}):\s{1,}(.{-})/\2/
```

Why `1s/\v(.{-}):\s{1,}(.{-})/\2""/`  convert the string into `""trailer` instead of `trailer""`?

Almost the same result:`1s/\v(.{-}):\s{1,}(.{-})/"\2"/`  convert the string into `""trailer` instead of `"trailer"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second capture group is non-gready and it captures nothing, so you essentially replace only `TE:`  with `\2` which is empty and `""`, and the result is `""trailer`.

```
1s/\v(.{-}):\s{1,}(.*)/\2""/
```

or

```
1s/\v(.{-}):\s{1,}(.{-})$/\2""/
```

would make it `trailer""`

and

```
1s/\v(.{-}):\s{1,}(.{-})$/\2""/
```

to make it `"trailer"`.

Comment: Indeed, I warned about the hazard of empty matches with non-greedy `.` in the OPs previous question.